# Display long HTML text in a web page c# code

Tags: c#

I am using C#.net

I have webpage, this page has a list view of "Reports IDs"

The requested functionality is Report Text should be displayed in a div when a user click on a report id in the list box.

Report Text is HTML format ( quite long around 16,000,000 char)

When I click on Report ID in the list box

I get this error

[image]

I added

```
<system.webServer>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
</system.webServer>
```

but still getting same error!

How to fix that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maximum request length exceeded.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853767/maximum-request-length-exceeded)

Comment: @GSerg yea that where i got my answer from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer

In system.web

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" executionTimeout="3600" />
```

And in system.webServer

```
<security>
    <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
    </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you!

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" maxRequestLength="1048576"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>

<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Rules:

- maxRequestLength (expressed in kb) value must match
  maxAllowedContentLength (expressed in bytes).
- most of the time your system.web section may already contains an
  "httpRuntime". set your targetFramework to the version of your .net
  used.

Notes:

- default value for maxRequestLength is 4096 (4mb). max value is
  2,147,483,647
- default value for maxAllowedContentLength is 30,000,000 (around
  30mb). max value is 4,294,967,295